# Numpy array output

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, python-3.x, numpy

Please help me! I've got following code which prints out transformed array

```
import numpy as np
from math import *


def walsh_transform(x):
    if len(x.shape) < 2:
        if len(x) > 3:
            n = len(x)
            m = trunc(log(n, 2))
            x = x[0:2 ** m]
            h2 = np.array([[1, 1], [1, -1]])
            for i in range(m - 1):
                if i == 0:
                    h = np.kron(h2, h2)
                else:
                    h = np.kron(h, h2)

            return np.dot(h, x) / 2. ** m,


temp_arr = []

arr = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
arr = np.array(arr)
for arr in walsh_transform(arr):
    temp_arr.append(arr)

print(type(temp_arr))
print(temp_arr)
```

I get the printed result as `[array([ 0.625, -0.125, -0.125,  0.125,  0.625, -0.125, -0.125,  0.125])]` thus temp_arr is a regular list: `<class 'list'>`. How to print it just like this?  `[ 0.625, -0.125, -0.125,  0.125,  0.625, -0.125, -0.125,  0.125]`

Answer (score 0):

What you actually have is a list of `numpy` arrays. If you only care about the first one, try `print(list(temp_arr[0]))`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of append try extend.

```
for arr in walsh_transform(arr):
    temp_arr.extend(arr)
```

Output :

```
[0.625, -0.125, -0.125, 0.125, 0.625, -0.125, -0.125, 0.125]
```